# MySQL ODBC driver installation error

Tags: mysql, macos, odbc, iodbc

When listing the ODBC drivers in iODBC, the MySQL drivers don't have any version numbers next to them. If I click on them to configure, I get an error saying "General Installer Error".

I've tried reinstalling the drivers via the oracle mysql connector installer, but no luck.  Any idea what could be wrong here?

[image: iODBC data sources]

Answer (score 0):

A version of `##.##` here indicates that iODBC couldn't fully load the driver to interrogate it about its version.  Among other installation errors, this may mean the driver library (and/or a library on which it depends) has incorrect permissions set, or there may be some library incompatibility at some layer.

Further troubleshooting would require review of the `~/Library/ODBC/odbcinst.ini` (User) and/or `/Library/ODBC/odbcinst.ini` (System) driver registration files; screenshots of the columns not visible here (note the horizontal scrollbar); output of `otool -L` against each of the driver libraries in question; and/or other information.  Such troubleshooting is not appropriate for this site; I would recommend pursuing assistance through the driver provider.

Worth noting -- [my employer](https://www.openlinksw.com/) maintains and supports [iODBC](http://www.iodbc.org/), and offers [alternative ODBC drivers for MySQL](https://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-mysql/); you may want to take advantage of the free two-week trial.